# Enable saml in Webshere Liberty

Tags: saml-2.0, websphere-liberty

Is this command required to enable saml in Liberty server?

```
bin/installUtility install samlWeb-2.0
```

I have configured `<feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>` in my server.xml and able to get metadata file using the url `https://ip:port/ibm/saml20/defaultSP/samlmetadata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `<feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>` that enables the feature, but you can't enable what you don't have, which is where `bin/installUtility` would come in (if necessary).

Liberty is available in several packages which dictate which set/sub-set of features are available immediately after installation (custom packages of Liberty can also be created to further customize the available set of features available to the runtime).  Features that are not included in the package can be installed afterwards using `bin/installUtility` (`bin/featureManager` has been deprecated).

The command `bin/installUtility install samlWeb-2.0` retrieves (from a repo) and installs the samlWeb-2.0 feature if it wasn't already installed in your Liberty runtime.  For example, if the Liberty package was that of just the Liberty Kernel, than `bin/installUtility install samlWeb-2.0` would download the samlWeb-2.0 feature along with all other pre-req features.  However, if your Liberty package was that of the entire Base edition (wlp-base-all) than it would already include the samlWeb-2.0 feature and you would not need to run `bin/installUtility` prior to enabling it.

Comment: As I'm able to get metadata file using the url https://ip:port/ibm/saml20/defaultSP/samlmetadata, I don't need to use installUtility. Please confirm.

Comment: Correct, your Liberty runtime already had the feature available.  
If if wasn't, than upon server start up, you would have seen a message printed regarding the samlWeb-2.0 feature not being available:
`CWWKF0042E: A feature definition cannot  be found for the  samlweb-2.0 feature.  Try running the command, bin/installUtility install samlweb-2.0,  to install the feature. Alternatively, you can run the command, bin/installUtility install defaultServer,  to install all features that are referenced by this configuration.`